# Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot \ln(x)^n \,dx $ for all positive n

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, recursion

I am trying to evaluate following integral for all positive n:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot \ln(x)^n \,dx
\end{equation}
,using partial integration,
\begin{equation}
\int u dv = uv - \int duv \\
u = \ln(x)^n,\quad\quad du = \frac{n\cdot \ln(x)^{n-1}}{x},\quad\quad dv=x^n,\quad\quad v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{equation}
I get the following:

\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{\ln(x)^n \cdot x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^1-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n\cdot \ln(x)^{n-1}}{x}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}dx
\end{equation}

Using L'Hospitals rule I evaluated the term with the square brackets to be $0$, so now I only have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{-n}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)^{n-1}\cdot x^{n}dx
\end{equation}
which is a nice recursive Integral, which yields:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n!}{(n+1)^n}
\end{equation}

But for my further calculations to work out I am supposed to get the following:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cdot n!}{n^n}
\end{equation}
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Neither of the two formula is correct. It should be $\dfrac{(-1)^n n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ (but if you want us to help you find where is your mistake, you should include how you solved the recursion...)

Comment: Perhaps easier to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot \ln(x)^m \,dx$...Integration by parts yields reduction formula $$\int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot \ln(x)^m \,dx = \frac{-m}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot \ln(x)^{m-1} \,dx$$  Then specialize $m=n$.